# Monitor Android device health remotely

Tags: android, monitoring

I am looking for a solution that lets me monitor the status of some Android devices remotely, recording things like RAM and storage usage, temperature etc.. It would also be good if it would save logcat output, and after a system crash send me the last logs.

I found a couple of solutions for app developers to monitor individual apps, but nothing to monitor the health of whole systems. Is there anything like this?